# What is the best way to save a lot of links?

Tags: java, database, jsoup

I am working on a program which gets all links from a website to use them later on. I am using the Java library JSoup to get the links form the website.

My problem is that I don't know where to store all links for later use. Every link has some attributes like "used" or "not used" and the date when it was used. It should also be Windows and Mac compatible. The saved data should be updateable, editable and the program should read the file where the data is saved fast.

Does anyone know a way to solve my problem?

Edit:

As my question wasn't clear for everyone here's a simpler question:

Should I store the links with their attributes in a database or in a file?

Comment: You can use an embedded database  like SQLite or Apache Derby

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to store on a single file I'd go for [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/). It's a SQL database provider that can save a whole database on a single file. SQLite databases are universally portable.

EDIT: As @bigdestroyer commented, Apache Derby is pure Java and may be another interesting option for you. I haven't used it though, but there is a [nice comparison here](http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=SqliteVersusDerby).

Comment: I'll try both to see which one suits me better. Thank you!

Comment: IMHO if you are not going to require a full SQL solution, SQLite has a much smaller memory footprint and it's handier to deal with (no user management).